# Как сделать такой выпадающий список?

Tags: javascript, html

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<label for="sidebar-value">Sheets:</label>
    <ul>
      <li ><input  type="checkbox" checked="checked"/><?= nameSpreadsheet();?></li>
      <ul>
           <? var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
                  var kol = ss.getNumSheets();
                  var as = ss.getSheets();
                  var data = [] ;
                  for (var i = 0 ; i < kol ; i++){
                     data [i] = as[i].getSheetName(); ?>
                    <li><input type="checkbox" checked="checked"><?= data[i] } ?> </li>
        </ul> 
   </ul>
```

Comment: подобный функционал возможно повторить даже без использования js, с помощью тега <details> и <summary>. Вот как пример, только поменять стилизацию и получиться как вам нужно: https://codepen.io/MoritzGiessmann/pen/PobErJB

Comment: Спасибо,помогло